# Special and generic points on Shimura varieites with the same special fiber

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $(G,X)$ be a Shimura datum of Hodge type. We say a point $x\in X$ is *generic* if the Mumford-Tate group of $x$ is the same as that of $X$ and *special* if the Mumford-Tate group of $x$ is a torus.

For a special point $x$, let $A_x$ be the corresponding abelian variety with CM and let $F$ be the field of definition. Let $v$ be a place of good reduction. 
Does there necessarily exist a generic point $y\in X$ such that the corresponding abelian variety $A_y$ has the same special fiber at $v$ as $A_x$?

If not, for what classes of Shimura varieties is this known?